# How to edit WooCommerce My Account page via hooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any other way to modify the WooCommerce template file than by overwriting it? For example, through certain hooks.

I see from the `woocommerce\templates\myaccount\dashboard.php` file that there seems to be a hooks named `woocommerce_account_dashboard`, can it customize the HTML output?

For example, use hooks to complete the following changes.

Original HTML output.

```
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
    <p>Hello<strong>Admin</strong>(not <strong>Admin</strong>? <a href="https://example.com/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=35de0b514e">Log out</a>)</p>
    <p>From your account dashboard you can view your <a href="https://example.com/my-account/orders/">recent orders</a> ,manage your <a href="https://example.com/my-account/edit-address/">shipping and billing addresses</a>,and <a href="https://example.com/my-account/edit-account/">edit your password and account details</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Modified HTML output.

```
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
    <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
    <p>Hello<strong>Admin</strong>(not <strong>Admin</strong>? <a href="https://example.com/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=35de0b514e">Log out</a>)</p>
    <p>From your account dashboard you can view your <a href="https://example.com/my-account/orders/">recent orders</a> ,and <a href="https://example.com/my-account/edit-account/">edit your password and account details</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Remove "`manage your shipping and billing addresses,` " from the HTML output.

Comment: The only way is overriding `myaccount/dashboard.php`template file via your child theme.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is right, thats the only way. Create a child theme and overwrite it by following this great documentation from WooCommerce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: @Mr.Jo Okay, thanks!